# HTML Table that will change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble with replicating this.
Im trying to make a table that changes based on the window size. When the window is large I want the table to look like the "large screen" graphic, and when the window is small I want the table to look like the "small screen" graphic.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What I have right now is this. When the window is large I have the desired layout.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

When I make the preview window smaller, my table collapses into one column instead of looking like how I want it to look like. IT should loook like the "small screen" graphic on the screenshot above.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Can u please explain more about your question?, i think i am not understanding this.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with additional information

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `display: block` for you media query display.

The default display value of table will be `display: table;` `thead` will be `display: table-header-group;`, `tbody` will be `display: table-row-group;`, `tr` will be `display: table-row;`, `th` and `td` will be `display: table-cell;`.

For the table header and body contents to fold in multiple lines, you have to make use of `display: block`, `float: left`, `box-sizing: border-box;`

To update the content of the header, you should do a tweek. Move the label `COMPARISON` to as span. On the smaller resolution, make the sapn hidden and add the content to `after` pseudo element.

```css
.table-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.flag-icon {
  margin-right: 0.1em;
}

.flex-row {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid palevioletred;
}

.flex-row,
.flex-cell {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table-container {
    display: block;
  }

  th,
  td {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
  }

  .flex-row {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .flex-row.first {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }

  thead,
  thead tr,
  tbody,
  tbody tr {
    display: block;
  }

  .header .flex-row.first span {
    display: none;
  }
  .header .flex-row.first:after {
    content: 'HOW THE PLAYERS COMPARE';
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-container" width="100%" role="table" aria-label="Destinations">
  <thead>
    <tr class="flex-table header" role="rowgroup">
      <th class="flex-row first" role="columnheader">
        <span>COMPARISON</span>
      </th>
      <th class="flex-row" role="columnheader">player 1</th>
      <th class="flex-row" role="columnheader">player 2</th>
      <th class="flex-row" role="columnheader">player 3</th>
      <th class="flex-row" role="columnheader">player 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="flex-table row" role="rowgroup">
      <td class="flex-row first" role="cell"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>Speed</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">11Sp </td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">22Sp</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">33Sp</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">44Sp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="flex-table row" role="rowgroup">
      <td class="flex-row first" role="cell"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>Endurance</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">11E </td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">22E</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">33E</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">44E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="flex-table row" role="rowgroup">
      <td class="flex-row first" role="cell"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>Strength</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">11St </td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">22S</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">33S</td>
      <td class="flex-row" role="cell">44S</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```